# kinectjs tween dynamic colour

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Is there a way to change the tween destination colour dynamically in Kinecticjs?

I've started with a rectangle and a tween with a destination colour, but I want to be able to change the destination colour dynamically. As an example, I've tried to access the Tween fillBlue property but it has no effect. This feature seemed to work in the previous KinectJS library but not 5.0. JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmh600/7HT46/

Thanks

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fillRed: 0,
    fillGreen: 128,
    fillBlue: 0,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
  });

  layer.add(rect);
  stage.add(layer);

    var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
            node: rect, 
            duration: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
            fillRed: 0,
            fillGreen: 0,
            fillBlue: 255
          }); 

    rect.on("mouseover", function() {
        tween.fillBlue = 0;
        tween.play();
    });
```

Comment: demo works fine for me. Chrome

Comment: strange - I was testing in Chrome 33.0.1750.152 on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that is working :

```
rect.on("mouseover", function() {
    tween._addAttr("fillBlue", 0);
    tween._addAttr("fillRed", 255);
    tween.play();
});
```